# How do I check whether have encoded in utf-8 successfully

Tags: python

Given a string

```
u ='abc'
```

which syntax is the right one to encode into utf8?

```
u.encode('utf-8')
```

or

```
u.encode('utf8')
```

And how do I know that I have already encoded in utr-8?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/library/codecs.html#standard-encodings - utf-8 is a valid alias for the utf_8 codec automatically (due to the hyphen-underscore conversion), and utf8 is in the list of aliases, so both are perfectly okay.

If encoding fails, you get an exception. Otherwise you can assume it succeeded.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all you need to make a distinction if you're talking about Python 2 or Python 3 because unicode handling is one of the biggest differences between the two versions.

### Python 2

- `unicode` type contains text characters
- `str` contains sequences of 8-bit bytes, sometimes representing text in some unspecified encoding
- `s.decode(encoding)` takes a sequence bytes and builds a text string out of it, once given the encoding used by the bytes. It goes from `str` to `unicode`, for example `"Citt\xe0".decode("iso8859-1")` will give you the text "Città" (Italian for city) and the same will happen for `"Citt\xc3\xa0".decode("utf-8")`. The encoding may be omitted and in that case the meaning is "use the default encoding".
- `u.encode(encoding)` takes a text string and builds the byte sequence representing it in the given encoding, thus reversing the processing of `decode`. It goes from `unicode` to `str`. As above the encoding can be omitted.

Part of the confusion when handling unicode with Python is that the language tries to be a bit too smart and does things automatically.

For example you can call `encode` also on an `str` object and the meaning is "encode the text that comes from decoding these bytes when using the default encoding, eventually using the specified encoding or the default encoding if not specified".

Similarly you can also call `decode` on an `unicode` object, meaning "decode the bytes that come from this text when using the default encoding, eventually using the specified encoding".

For example if I write

```
u"Citt\u00e0".decode("utf-8")
```

Python gives as error:

> UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xe0' in
>                       position 3: ordinal not in range(128)

NOTE: the error is about **encoding** that failed, while I asked for **decoding**. The reason is that I asked to decode text (nonsense because that is already "decoded"... it's text) and Python decided to first encode it using the "ascii" encoding and that failed. IMO much better would have to just not have `decode` on unicode objects and not have `encode` on string objects: the error message would have been clearer.

More confusion is that in Python 2 `str` is used for unencoded **bytes**, but it's also used everywhere for text and for example string literals are `str` objects.

### Python 3

To solve some of the issues Python 3 made a few key changes

- `str` is for text and contains unicode characters, string literals are unicode text
- `unicode` type doesn't exist any more
- `bytes` type is used for 8-bit bytes sequences that may represent text in some unspecified encoding

For example in Python 3

```
'Città'.encode('iso8859-1') → b'Citt\xe0'
'Città'.encode('utf-8')     → b'Citt\xc3\xa0'
```

also you cannot call `decode` on text strings and you cannot call `encode` on byte sequences.

### Failures

Sometimes encoding text into bytes may fail, because the specified encoding cannot handle all of unicode. For example `iso8859-1` cannot handle Chinese. These errors can be processed in a few ways like raising an exception (default), or replacing characters that cannot be encoded with something else.

The encoding `utf-8` however is able to encode any unicode character and thus encoding to `utf-8` never fails. **Thus it doesn't make sense to ask how to know if encoding text into `utf-8` was done correctly, because it always happens (for `utf-8`).**

Also decoding may fail, because the sequence of bytes may make no sense in the specified encoding. For example the sequence of bytes `0x43 0x69 0x74 0x74 0xE0` cannot be interpreted as `utf-8` because the byte `0xE0` cannot appear without a proper prefix.

There are encodings like `iso8859-1` where however decoding cannot fail because any byte 0..255 has a meaning as a character. Most "local encodings" are of this type... they map all 256 possible 8-bit values to some character, but only covering a tiny fraction of the unicode characters.

Decoding using `iso8859-1` will never raise an error (any byte sequence is valid) but of course it can give you nonsense text if the bytes where using another encoding.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I am crystal clear for the concept now :)

Answer (score 0):

First solution:

```
isinstance(u, unicode)
```

Second solution:

```
try:
    u.decode('utf-8')
    print "string is UTF-8, length %d bytes" % len(string)
except UnicodeError:
    print "string is not UTF-8"
```